# Drupal 7 - How to redirect a user to a certain page until they change a setting on that page?

Tags: drupal, redirect, drupal-7

How can I force Drupal 7 to redirect the user to a certain page (which contains a form) wherever the user clicks on the site, after they logged in, until they fill out that form?

Eg.: Anon User arrives to the site, they can browse around no problem.
Once they login/register, I would like to show a page (with a form) and not allow
them to go anywhere else until they fill that form out.

This solution has to work with cached pages so hook_init() can't be used. 
hook_boot() seemed a good idea, but it is loading too early and lots of required includes won't load.

Also, the solution has to check if the page request is the actual form submit (otherwise they won't be able to submit the form)

Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: why can't you use hook_init on cached pages ? Once you clear the cache hook init will be a perfect fit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that hook_init() is the solution and the problem was caused by the $user object. The trick is, that you have to reload the $user object, as the global doesn't contain the field values.

Very simple example code:

```
function mymodule_init(){
    global $user;

    if($user->uid && $user->uid != 1){

        $account = user_load($user->uid);
        $account = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $account);

        $destination = drupal_get_destination();

        if(!$account->field_setup_completed->value()){
            drupal_set_message('Setup incomplete.', 'error');

            if($destination['destination'] != 'setup-page' && $destination['destination'] != 'user/logout'){
                drupal_set_message('Redirecting to setup', 'error');
                drupal_goto('setup-page');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I must ask...are you using `entity_metadata_wrapper()` for any particular reason? It's an unnecessary extra step as you can just test for `$account->field_setup_completed[$user->language][0]['value']` once you've called `user_load()`. The reason I ask is because I've never seen it used in this way before and I'd be interested to know your reasoning :)

Comment: Clive, you are right, no point converting it there, I just got used to it as I work mainly with entities. (also, I intend to use that $account object later on to make changes to the user, but that's not part of the example)